# How to autoreload a .npy file in Python3 Script?

Tags: python, numpy

How to autoreload a .npy file in Python3 Script? 
I generate .npy files in one Script (A.py), and in another script (B.py) I need to renew plots which are generated from those .npy files. 
Since .npy file is not a module, putting these sentence(`# %reload_ext autoreload # %autoreload 2`) at the beigining of B.py doesn't solve the problem.

I have Python 3.5.2, IPython 7.1.1 and OS: Ubuntu 16.04.

Add: I run B.py indirectly from LaTex, and the execution of B.py will only be triggered when Python interpreter detects a change in B.py.

Comment: I don't know much about Numpy so I'm probably wrong, but couldn't you just load the npy file several times with `numpy.load()`?

Comment: I run B.py indirectly from LaTex, and the execution of B.py will only be triggered when Python interpreter detects a change in B.py. Thus i wouln't manually execute the np.load() command.

Comment: This seems more like a question about latex.  Is there a way to trigger the execution when the `npy` file changes?

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening. The problem is solved now: in my LaTex project I specified in the Makefile that changes in the .npy files will trigger an execution of B.py. Now I get automatically renewed plot when the .npy files change.